# Positioning a div element over absolutely-positioned image

Tags: html, css

I have two images that are placed on top of each other (one absolutely positioned), so that I can hover over one to see the other. I'd like to also position a "text box" (a div with a colored background that can hold some simple text) that spans the lower 1/4th of the top image, however, I'm running into some issues trying to position said text box when the image underneath it is already absolutely positioned.

I've attached a sample codepen below, and an image of what I'm ideally going for. Is there a simple way to do this with HTML/CSS?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jensjohnson/pen/dKBrGy)

```
<img src="img1.foo" class="img1" />
<img src="img2.foo" class="img2" />
<div class="textBar">Text bar here?</div>
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42pPR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKEEKb

Css to add to the "tag" class:

```
.tag {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3; /*place above the images */
  bottom: 0; /* put it at the bottom */
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* allow for padding to be included in width */
}
```

also you can do this without jquery using the css `:hover` 
pseudo class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover :

```
img.front:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!